# Firefox missing "I Understand the Risks" icon

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have this page and there is not "I Understand the Risks" icon ion it so ,i asked for help:

[image]

and the Firefox is :

[[image]

And my OS version is:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.

Comment: well, the expired certificate should not stop you. when I use firefox I get the the "Accept risk and continue" button. BTW, why dont you use sci-hub.tw instead of the IP as this goes through without issues as it has a valid trusted certificate.... the answer for you Q could be [here - invalid security certificate add exception button missing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1206414)

Comment: You have a HSTS entry cached for 186.2.163.227. HSTS cannot be circumvented.

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing the site by its IP address `186.2.163.90`, and encountering
the following problems:

- The certificate is only valid for the following names: `*.sci-hub.tw`, `sci-hub.tw`
- The certificate expired on Sunday 3 May 2020.

If you use instead the website `sci-hub.tw` in the URL and the certificate
was totally refused, then
you could fix it by removing it from the file `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt`
residing inside your Firefox profile folder.

If all fails, just use another browser.

I note that in my case Firefox does allow me to advance to this website,
but that this page is just empty.